# Is there a way to open files with Notepad++ in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows?

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, notepad++, command-line-interface

I am on Windows 10 but I am using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (WSL) to familiarize myself with the Linux command line.

I am trying to take full advantage of its capabilities and was thinking it would be awesome to be able to open, say, `index.html` from the CLI in Notepad++. Is this possible? If so, how would I go about setting it up?

I am pretty new to the command line in general, much less Linux commands.

Comment: something like `"/path/to/c/drive/program files/notepad++/notepad++.exe" index.html`... You can create bash functions to make it look tinier and cleaner.

Comment: On-topic.  Ubuntu on Windows is a "software tool commonly used by programmers" (or at least, that's what it is intended for).

Answer (score 21):

> It is absolutely possible to use Notepad++ in WSL. In fact, you can use it in precisely the same way as if working in a normal Windows environment.

You need to create a bash *alias* to allow for easier use of the following command:

`<path_to_textEditor> <path_to_textfile>`

---

To create an alias for Notepad++, do the following in WSL bash:

1. Open your `.bashrc` startup script (runs when bash is started):

   `vim ~/.bashrc`
2. Add the alias defintion to the script:

   `alias np='<path_to_textEditor>'`

   For Notepad++ it would be:

   `alias np='/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe'`

   You might have to adjust the path if you didn't install Notepad++ in the default directory.

   Make sure to escape any special characters, like whitespaces, with the escape chatacter `\` (backslash).

Now, use it like you would normally:

To open Notepad++, do `np`

To open a specific file in Notepad++, do `np <text_file>`

---

> As suggested by user @ericpeters, there are several useful [Notepad++
>   startup options](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Command_Line_Switches) that you might want to add to your alias.

These startup options are appended to the end of the alias string and separated by whitespaces.

`alias np='<path_to_textEditor> <startup_option_1> <startup_option_2> ...'`

Here are some examples:

- `-multiInst`: Open an new Notepad++ instance that is separate from the currently opened Notepad++ session (if it exists).
- `-nosession`: Don't load the previous session and don't save the session to `session.xml`.
- `-notabbar`: Turn off the tab interface.

Here's an example with startup options:

```
alias np='/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe -multiInst -notabbar -nosession'
```

Personally, I have two separate aliases, one without startup options and one with the three startup options above. This allows me to choose if I want to:

- Quickly edit individual files when I don't want to use VIM (and return to the CLI when exiting). Useful for writing git commit messages.
- Open up files into my 'always open' standard Notepad++ session (with tabs).

Comment: when I try np <filename> Notepad++ starts, but it fails with error "Unable to translate current working directory. Using C:\windows\system32" and it does not open the file <filename>.

Comment: @FelixOgg, it could be that there is no Windows equivalent to the path you are trying to access, or that it should not be accessed via NT processes. Maybe you can find help here: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2011#issuecomment-297519769

Comment: Because I have muscle memory to type `mate` I simply add `alias mate='/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin' into my ~/.bashrc file...this allows me to do something like: $ mate jvm/src/main/scala/fm/common/InputStreamResource.scala and it will open up, and it will keep that command open until I close the file

Comment: Good idea @ericpeters, I didn't think about startup options when I initially wrote the answer. Added.

Answer (score 2):

I usually put all work files in Windows directory

```
/mnt/d/ubuntu/
```

Then in WSL Ubuntu shell, I create a symbolic link to the directory

```
ln -s /mnt/d/ubuntu ~/win
```

Whatever files I work with in WSL, I put them in this directory except for the linux specific files, which usually have no need to be opened with Windows applications.

Now, when you want to use Windows applications for the files, you simply browse the app to

```
D:/ubuntu/.../your/files
```

Answer (score 1):

For WSL2 I just add Notepad++ dir to the `PATH` and put there that script:

```
#!/bin/bash

params=()
args=($@)
argslength=${#args[@]}
for (( i=0; i<${argslength}; i++ ));
do
  param=${args[$i]}
  if [[ ${param:0:1} == "/" ]]; then
    params[$i]=$(wslpath -w $param)
  else
    params[$i]=$param
  fi
done

notepad++.exe ${params[@]}
```

It converts absolute paths (in a naive yet simple way) to Windows format so that Notepad++ can understand them.

I usually just name the script as `npp` and my `git ecg` works again.

```
git config --global alias.ecg "config --global -e"
git config --global core.editor "npp -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```