# In the Ubuntu Bash shell in Windows 10, how do you open a file or directory with the default program?

Tags: windows, bash, shell

E.g., if I have `.java` files set to open with Notepad++, is there some command I can run like `open ./Blah.java` that will open Blah.java in Notepad++, or `open .` to open the current directory in Explorer? On Mac OS X, `open` is this command.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not Unix tech support. Try unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71192/open-any-kind-of-application-with-bash

Comment: This might be interesting for those who are looking for a solution to Notepad++ specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49186223/6292000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something that wraps the [ShellExecute function](//webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Rmuy-aLdgnUJ:msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb762153).

With Cygwin, this is `cygstart`.

With PowerShell, this is `Start-Process`.

You can run PowerShell from the Bash shell, but it is not ideal:

```
powershell Start-Process Blah.java
```

This is currently a [feature request](//wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/15590718-equivalent-of-cgystart-open-or-xdg-open) for Ubuntu on Windows.