# Windows bash equivalent of start in bash

Tags: windows, bash, command

Does it exist? For example, in Windows Bash, I can do this:

```
start my-file.py # by default, .py gets executed, so it does
start https://github.com # opens github.com
```

How can I do this in `bash`

Answer (score 1):

These applications are part of the operating system and not the shell.

The shell is simply a program that allows you to enter commands for the operating system. Windows comes with `cmd` and the new PowerShell. Linux comes with many shells, but the default in almost all distributions is `bash`, but there are many others that people use, one of the more popular ones is `zsh`.

macos also comes as default with bash, but just like Linux you can install alternative shells on it.

So the program `start` is actually part of Windows, you would need to find the equivalent for whatever operating system you are using that is running `bash`.

- In Windows, you can use `start`
- On macos, you can use `open`

On Linux, if available, you can try `xdg-open`, but this requires you to be running a desktop session, from the [`man` page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open):

> xdg-open opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application. If a
>   URL is provided the URL will be opened in the user's preferred web
>   browser. If a file is provided the file will be opened in the
>   preferred application for files of that type. xdg-open supports file,
>   ftp, http and https URLs.
>
> xdg-open is for use inside a desktop session only. It is not recommended to use xdg-open as root.

Answer (score 0):

You need something that wraps the [ShellExecute function](//webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Rmuy-aLdgnUJ:msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb762153).

With Cygwin, this is `cygstart`.

With PowerShell, this is `Start-Process`.

You can run PowerShell from the Bash shell, but it is not ideal:

```
powershell Start-Process Blah.java
```

This is currently a [feature request](//wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/15590718-equivalent-of-cgystart-open-or-xdg-open) for Ubuntu on Windows.

[In the Ubuntu Bash shell in Windows 10, how do you open a file or directory with the default program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40352267/#40370009)